# What causes certain lines of a webpages to get highlighted in my brower

Tags: chromium, user-interface, dark-mode

[image]

My web browser shows up certain lines of text as highlighted in yellow, which is of no purpose. When I refresh the site this effect disappears. 
Happens with many sites other than wikipidea. More often than not with stackexchange sites as well. 
What's actually causing it. How to stop it from happening. 
I'm using Microsoft chromium edge Version 83.0.478.54 (Official build) (64-bit).
I also have dark reader extension installed on my browser.

Comment: Are you coming to the site from a search engine? Your address bar shows a highlight text expression.

Comment: Answer updated with instructions to disable this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's actually causing it?

> Google launches featured snippet to web page content highlight feature
>
> After years of testing, Google now launched the featured snippet to
> web page highlight feature.
>
> **How it works.**
>
> Do a search on Google on desktop or mobile, and if you see a featured
> snippet, click on it. After you click on it, Google may anchor you
> down and/or highlight the text on that web page that you saw in the
> featured snippet.

Source: [Google launches featured snippet to web page content highlight feature](https://searchengineland.com/google-launches-featured-snippet-to-web-page-content-highlight-feature-335511)

> What happens when a user clicks a featured snippet?

> Clicking a featured snippet takes the user directly to the featured snippet text on the source web page. This happens automatically. There's no markup needed by webmasters to enable a featured snippet. If a browser doesn't support the underlying technology needed, or if our systems can't confidently determine exactly where within a page to direct a click, clicking a featured snippet will take a user to the top of the source web page.

Source: [Featured snippets and your website - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325)

I can't find any way to disable it.

---

#### How can I disable it?

1. Open Chrome and visit `chrome://flags/`
2. Look for the section, `scrollToTextFragment`, or just enter `chrome://flags/#enable-text-fragment-anchor` in the address bar
3. Select `Disabled` from the dropdown menu

Source: [How to Disable Chrome Scroll to Text Fragment | Perishable Press](https://perishablepress.com/disable-chrome-scrolltotextfragment/)

---

#### Related

- [What's with the new querystring text highlighting feature in Chrome? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1556904/whats-with-the-new-querystring-text-highlighting-feature-in-chrome)
- [Strange highlighting for a few seconds - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398033/strange-highlighting-for-a-few-seconds#:%7E:text=Stack%20Overflow%20could,%20entirely)